# How to add Action bar to main screen when using navcontroller?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am creating a project in which i would like to have following phenomenon. The first activity can be launched from an intent. When it is launched it has a back button on action bar. There are further destinations from this activity which i have set up using navcontroller. I have set up actionbar with navcontroller. But it removes the back button from main screen . What should i do to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the back button on action bar in your main activity:

```
 supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```